Vulkan SDK Demos not runnable
When running the Vulkan SDK demos (e.g.: vkcubecpp) (by opening DEMOS.sln) it gives me this error: cannot open source file volk.h. I noticed this and checked the Inlude folder in the VulkanSDK to see if Volk was installed, and in fact, it wasn't. It is an optional component. So, to run the demos, this optional component needs to be included. I did that, but I had to change the include line to #include "Volk/volk.h". (Even though, in the Visual Studio Project, the whole Include folder is being listed in the "Additional Include Libraries", it doesn't seem to find the files) After doing so, when building cube.cpp with the local Windows Debugger in Visual Studio 2022, I receive a vast amount of errors. (see lines below)
Build started at 17:06...
1>------ Build started: Project: vkcubepp, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>cube.cpp
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_structs.hpp(67568,35): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_structs.hpp(67568,30): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_structs.hpp(67568,117): error C2612: trailing ')' illegal in base/member initializer list
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(21,93): error C2039: 'InstanceCreateInfo': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(22,93): error C2039: 'AllocationCallbacks': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(23,87): error C2039: 'Instance': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(34,89): error C2039: 'Instance': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(35,33): error C2039: 'InstanceCreateInfo': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(35,103): error C2039: 'AllocationCallbacks': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(54,102): error C2039: 'Instance': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(55,33): error C2039: 'InstanceCreateInfo': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(55,103): error C2039: 'AllocationCallbacks': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(76,73): error C2039: 'AllocationCallbacks': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(76,36): error C2888: 'void vk::Instance::destroy(const vk::AllocationCallbacks *,const Dispatch &) noexcept const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(84,82): error C2039: 'AllocationCallbacks': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(84,36): error C2888: 'void vk::Instance::destroy(vk::Optional<const vk::AllocationCallbacks>,const Dispatch &) noexcept const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(98,107): error C2039: 'PhysicalDevice': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(97,59): error C2888: 'vk::Result vk::Instance::enumeratePhysicalDevices(uint32_t *,vk::PhysicalDevice *,const Dispatch &) noexcept const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(107,101): error C2039: 'PhysicalDevice': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(108,34): error C2888: 'ResultValueType<std::vector<vk::PhysicalDevice,PhysicalDeviceAllocator>>::type vk::Instance::enumeratePhysicalDevices(const Dispatch &) const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(139,118): error C2039: 'PhysicalDevice': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(140,101): error C2039: 'PhysicalDevice': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(141,34): error C2888: 'ResultValueType<std::vector<vk::PhysicalDevice,PhysicalDeviceAllocator>>::type vk::Instance::enumeratePhysicalDevices(PhysicalDeviceAllocator &,const Dispatch &) const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(172,77): error C2039: 'PhysicalDeviceFeatures': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(172,42): error C2888: 'void vk::PhysicalDevice::getFeatures(vk::PhysicalDeviceFeatures *,const Dispatch &) noexcept const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(180,64): error C2039: 'PhysicalDeviceFeatures': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(181,58): error C2888: 'vk::PhysicalDeviceFeatures vk::PhysicalDevice::getFeatures(const Dispatch &) noexcept const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(196,85): error C2039: 'Format': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(197,85): error C2039: 'FormatProperties': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(196,42): error C2888: 'void vk::PhysicalDevice::getFormatProperties(vk::Format,vk::FormatProperties *,const Dispatch &) noexcept const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(206,64): error C2039: 'FormatProperties': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(207,64): error C2039: 'Format': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(207,21): error C2888: 'vk::FormatProperties vk::PhysicalDevice::getFormatProperties(vk::Format,const Dispatch &) noexcept const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(222,113): error C2039: 'Format': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(223,113): error C2039: 'ImageType': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(224,113): error C2039: 'ImageTiling': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(225,113): error C2039: 'ImageUsageFlags': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(226,113): error C2039: 'ImageCreateFlags': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(227,113): error C2039: 'ImageFormatProperties': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(222,65): error C2888: 'vk::Result vk::PhysicalDevice::getImageFormatProperties(vk::Format,vk::ImageType,vk::ImageTiling,vk::ImageUsageFlags,vk::ImageCreateFlags,vk::ImageFormatProperties *,const Dispatch &) noexcept const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(242,89): error C2039: 'ImageFormatProperties': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(243,88): error C2039: 'Format': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(244,69): error C2039: 'ImageType': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(245,69): error C2039: 'ImageTiling': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(246,69): error C2039: 'ImageUsageFlags': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(247,69): error C2039: 'ImageCreateFlags': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(243,40): error C2888: 'vk::ResultValue<T> vk::PhysicalDevice::getImageFormatProperties(vk::Format,vk::ImageType,vk::ImageTiling,vk::ImageUsageFlags,vk::ImageCreateFlags,const Dispatch &) const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(243,40): error C2888:         with
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(243,40): error C2888:         [
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(243,40): error C2888:             T=vk::ImageFormatProperties
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(243,40): error C2888:         ]
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(271,79): error C2039: 'PhysicalDeviceProperties': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(271,42): error C2888: 'void vk::PhysicalDevice::getProperties(vk::PhysicalDeviceProperties *,const Dispatch &) noexcept const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(280,64): error C2039: 'PhysicalDeviceProperties': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(281,58): error C2888: 'vk::PhysicalDeviceProperties vk::PhysicalDevice::getProperties(const Dispatch &) noexcept const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(297,90): error C2039: 'QueueFamilyProperties': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(296,42): error C2888: 'void vk::PhysicalDevice::getQueueFamilyProperties(uint32_t *,vk::QueueFamilyProperties *,const Dispatch &) noexcept const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(307,76): error C2039: 'QueueFamilyProperties': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(308,58): error C2888: 'std::vector<vk::QueueFamilyProperties,QueueFamilyPropertiesAllocator> vk::PhysicalDevice::getQueueFamilyProperties(const Dispatch &) const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(333,117): error C2039: 'QueueFamilyProperties': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(334,76): error C2039: 'QueueFamilyProperties': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(335,21): error C2888: 'std::vector<vk::QueueFamilyProperties,QueueFamilyPropertiesAllocator> vk::PhysicalDevice::getQueueFamilyProperties(QueueFamilyPropertiesAllocator &,const Dispatch &) const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(359,85): error C2039: 'PhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(359,42): error C2888: 'void vk::PhysicalDevice::getMemoryProperties(vk::PhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties *,const Dispatch &) noexcept const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(368,64): error C2039: 'PhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(369,58): error C2888: 'vk::PhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties vk::PhysicalDevice::getMemoryProperties(const Dispatch &) noexcept const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(384,50): error C2888: 'PFN_vkVoidFunction vk::Instance::getProcAddr(const char *,const Dispatch &) noexcept const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(392,50): error C2888: 'PFN_vkVoidFunction vk::Instance::getProcAddr(const std::string &,const Dispatch &) noexcept const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(406,48): error C2888: 'PFN_vkVoidFunction vk::Device::getProcAddr(const char *,const Dispatch &) noexcept const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(414,48): error C2888: 'PFN_vkVoidFunction vk::Device::getProcAddr(const std::string &,const Dispatch &) noexcept const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(428,107): error C2039: 'DeviceCreateInfo': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(429,107): error C2039: 'AllocationCallbacks': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(430,101): error C2039: 'Device': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(428,65): error C2888: 'vk::Result vk::PhysicalDevice::createDevice(const vk::DeviceCreateInfo *,const vk::AllocationCallbacks *,vk::Device *,const Dispatch &) noexcept const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(442,89): error C2039: 'Device': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(443,33): error C2039: 'DeviceCreateInfo': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(443,101): error C2039: 'AllocationCallbacks': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(442,119): error C2888: 'vk::ResultValue<T> vk::PhysicalDevice::createDevice(const vk::DeviceCreateInfo &,vk::Optional<const vk::AllocationCallbacks>,const Dispatch &) const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(442,119): error C2888:         with
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(442,119): error C2888:         [
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(442,119): error C2888:             T=vk::Device
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(442,119): error C2888:         ]
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(463,102): error C2039: 'Device': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(464,88): error C2039: 'DeviceCreateInfo': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(465,78): error C2039: 'AllocationCallbacks': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(464,40): error C2888: 'ResultValueType<vk::UniqueHandle<vk::Device,Dispatch>>::type vk::PhysicalDevice::createDeviceUnique(const vk::DeviceCreateInfo &,vk::Optional<const vk::AllocationCallbacks>,const Dispatch &) const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(488,71): error C2039: 'AllocationCallbacks': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(488,34): error C2888: 'void vk::Device::destroy(const vk::AllocationCallbacks *,const Dispatch &) noexcept const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(496,80): error C2039: 'AllocationCallbacks': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(496,34): error C2888: 'void vk::Device::destroy(vk::Optional<const vk::AllocationCallbacks>,const Dispatch &) noexcept const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(511,109): error C2039: 'ExtensionProperties': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(521,101): error C2039: 'ExtensionProperties': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(555,115): error C2039: 'ExtensionProperties': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(556,101): error C2039: 'ExtensionProperties': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(593,123): error C2039: 'ExtensionProperties': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(591,65): error C2888: 'vk::Result vk::PhysicalDevice::enumerateDeviceExtensionProperties(const char *,uint32_t *,vk::ExtensionProperties *,const Dispatch &) noexcept const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(603,101): error C2039: 'ExtensionProperties': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(604,40): error C2888: 'ResultValueType<std::vector<vk::ExtensionProperties,ExtensionPropertiesAllocator>>::type vk::PhysicalDevice::enumerateDeviceExtensionProperties(vk::Optional<const std::string>,const Dispatch &) const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(637,115): error C2039: 'ExtensionProperties': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(638,101): error C2039: 'ExtensionProperties': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(639,40): error C2888: 'ResultValueType<std::vector<vk::ExtensionProperties,ExtensionPropertiesAllocator>>::type vk::PhysicalDevice::enumerateDeviceExtensionProperties(vk::Optional<const std::string>,ExtensionPropertiesAllocator &,const Dispatch &) const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(674,105): error C2039: 'LayerProperties': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(683,101): error C2039: 'LayerProperties': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(715,119): error C2039: 'LayerProperties': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(716,101): error C2039: 'LayerProperties': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(749,119): error C2039: 'LayerProperties': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(748,65): error C2888: 'vk::Result vk::PhysicalDevice::enumerateDeviceLayerProperties(uint32_t *,vk::LayerProperties *,const Dispatch &) noexcept const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(758,101): error C2039: 'LayerProperties': is not a member of 'vk::vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(759,40): error C2888: 'ResultValueType<std::vector<vk::LayerProperties,LayerPropertiesAllocator>>::type vk::PhysicalDevice::enumerateDeviceLayerProperties(const Dispatch &) const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'vk'
1>C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.283.0_v2\Include\vulkan\vulkan_funcs.hpp(759,40): error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
1>Done building project "vkcubepp.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build completed at 17:06 and took 00,913 seconds ==========

What am I doing wrong here? I assumed that opening the Visual Studio files properly sets up the include paths etc, so I thought I would not have to worry too much about that. Also, my Vulkan SDK installation is fine, I verified it according to the docs, so I run vkvia, vulkaninfoSDK and vkcube and everything seems to work just fine.
